# Position fixid on vertically scroll, but not horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

Example:

```
<div>
   <div class="sloth">
       Header1
   </div>

   <div class="sloth">
       Header2
   </div>
</div>
```

The first half day i tried to set the position of all elements with the same class to fixed to scroll vertically to show always the header text. It worked, but there is a little problem. It worked horizontally too.

I tried some things to block horizontally or reset the position for the elements, but i have not working code.

i can 't use overflow-x:hidden, cause it is a requirement to see and use the scrollbar.

After long searching on Google,  i found no working solution.

The elements are somewhere in the middle of the mvc3 HTML Page.

Any ideas? Only show Headers on scroll vertically,  but not horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use some javascript to determine the horizontal scroll and handle the left position...See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7pmrrtsc/4/)

This javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
   $('#stickMe').css('left', ($(window).scrollLeft() * -1) );
});
```

For this CSS

```
#stickMe{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding:40px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: Oh i see my work is near your solution. I haven't the '* -1' part. Thank you!

Comment: Yep--you need to give the `left:` a negative value--so essentially it is moving it to the left as you scroll.

Comment: Maybe you know another thing. I use drag & drop in javascript. I drag table from on div in another. In Firefox it worked fine on every window scroll position. In IE it worked it only in the visible area after pageload. After scolling to another position, the drop event can ' t fire, cause it isn't allowed anymore. Any idea why this bug in IE?